# Serilog - Logging on Multiple Threads Stalls App Cancellation

Tags: c#, multithreading, elasticsearch, serilog

I'm having trouble with graceful shutdown of a .NET Core app that is logging to the Serilog ElasticSearch sink from multiple threads. Below is a minimum working example:

`Program.cs`:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main() =>
        await new HostBuilder()
            .UseConsoleLifetime()
            .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) => logging.AddSerilog(
                new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(
                        nodeUris: "http://example.com:9200",
                        indexFormat: "derp-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}",
                        typeName: "_doc"
                    )
                .CreateLogger(), dispose: true)
            )
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<DerpService>();
            })
        .Build()
        .RunAsync();
}
```

`DerpService.cs`:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class DerpService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<DerpService> _logger;
    public DerpService(ILogger<DerpService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) =>
        await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable
            .Range(0, 100)
            .Select(i =>
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation($"Task {i} is here!");
                    }
                }, stoppingToken)
        ));
}
```

When I run this app, Serilog immediately starts writing a whole bunch of `Task i is here!` messages to Console, but nothing gets logged to ElasticSearch for 
 several minutes. Once the ElasticSearch logs do start, they fall increasingly behind as the app continues. In addition, the app's memory consumption blows up, seemingly without bound, with `Serilog.Events.LogEvent` instances. Finally, when I then try to cancel the app with `Ctrl+C` in the console window, the console logs stop, and the memory consumption tapers off, but the app remains alive for several minutes longer, presumably while Serilog chews through the backlog of `LogEvent`s to send to ElasticSearch.

So clearly I'm hammering the Serilog ElasticSearch sink with more concurrent logs than it was ever meant to handle, but these seem like potentially annoying problems for *any* multi-threaded app with logging. Specifically:

1. Does the ElasticSearch have some maximum logging rate that it can handle? Are there any good ways to make it faster?
2. I thought .NET Core generic hosts were supposed to [shutdown automatically after 5 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host#shutdown-timeout). What about the ElasticSearch sink is preventing the host from shutting down the app?
3. Is there some way to force cancellation of Serilog after `Ctrl+C` instructs the app to shutdown (assuming I don't care about the remaining log events)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you attached a debugger and checked where threads are blocked?

Yes, BackgroundService will abandon the Task if it takes more than the given shutdown timeout. https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/88641b5021c880822281adf7d63298a3b5a145a2/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L65